# Should pizza be firm enough to be held by the crust?

Tags: pizza

I've been to 4 restaurants already (with good reviews) and they all serve similar pizzas - they have to be eaten with fork and knife or else they will bend (because one simply can't hold them with a hand) and their contents will most likely fall off.Even cutting them with a knife completely disintegrates the pizza so in the end it turns into a weird salad of dough, tomato sauce, cheese etc.Is this what pizzas are really supposed to be like?

Comment: Where are you located? This will probably vary by country (or even state, if in the US).

Comment: Europe (south eastern).

Comment: Yeah, so you get Northern Italian pizza mostly, I'll bet.  Those are super-thin-crust, and are *meant* to be eaten with fork & knife.

Comment: I did up voted giorgiosironi's A but I would add that the good of pizza is to come in a virtually infinite number of variations (within a finite space). Even in Italy. But the tip of a slice holds only very very seldom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking as an Italian, both Neapolitan-style pizza (thicker crust on the border) and rest-of-ITaly-style pizza will have a thin center that will normally bend when cut or held; the more so if there are lots of toppings. It shouldn't really disintegrate, that may be an indication of a bad knife, too.

Normally bending dough isn't a problem because you can fold the slice:
[image]

Comment: This, it's the top of the pizza that bends (the point).I've found that rolling it is the most efficient way to eat it (though I haven't tried to fold it).How many styles are there and which types are firm enough not to bend?

Comment: @JoeDough Folding creates an arch, which will provide support for the entire slice, all the way down to the tip.

Answer (score 9):

It's not uncommon for a slice of pizza to "droop" in the front if you try to pick it up with one hand. The amount of droop will vary, depending on the toppings, and type of dough.

Thin, crispy crust pizza will tend to hold itself when picked up. However, longer, thinner, softer dough tends to droop under the weight of itself and the toppings.

There's three main ways to deal with this:

**1) Use two hands to hold the slice:**

[image]

Image Source: [123rf.com](https://us.123rf.com/450wm/bnenin/bnenin1803/bnenin180300039/97156000-woman-holding-slice-of-pizza-close-up.jpg?ver=6)

**2) Use your thumb to support the pizza while your index and middle finger hold the crust:**

[image]

Image Source: [alamy.com](https://l7.alamy.com/comp/X3XM44/close-up-of-a-mature-woman-holding-a-slice-of-pizza-X3XM44.jpg)

**3) Fold the slice into a "U" shape, which creates an arch, and will provide rigidity for your pizza!** It doesn't need to be folded completely in half, just a slight "U" shape will do.

[image] [image]

Image Source: [seriouseats.com](https://slice.seriouseats.com/images/20100714-foldhold-full-lede.jpg)    [wired.com](https://media.wired.com/photos/593245a852d99d6b984dd65d/master/w_660,c_limit/pizza-fold-hold.png)